# XML Parser returns last item, not the rest

Tags: android, android-xml

my XML Content: (FileName: sku.xml)

```
<skus>
<id>p1</id>
<id>test</id>
<id>aa</id>
<id>bb</id>
<id>cc</id>
<id>dd</id>
<id>ee</id>
<id>ff</id>
<id>gg</id>
<id>hh</id>
<id>ii</id>
<id>jj</id>
<id>kk</id>
<id>ll</id>
</skus>
```

my SAX XML PARSER Class:

public class SAXXMLParser {

```
public static List<XMLSetAdd> parse(InputStream is) {
    List<XMLSetAdd> setAdds = null;
    try {
        // create a XMLReader from SAXParser
        XMLReader xmlReader = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser()
                .getXMLReader();
        // create a SAXXMLHandler
        SAXXMLHANDLER saxHandler = new SAXXMLHANDLER();
        // store handler in XMLReader
        xmlReader.setContentHandler(saxHandler);
        // the process starts
        xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(is));
        // get the News list`
        setAdds = saxHandler.getIds();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("XML", "SAXXMLParser: parse() failed");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    // return News list
    return setAdds;
}
```

}

My SAX XML HANDLER:

```
public class SAXXMLHANDLER extends DefaultHandler {

    private List<XMLSetAdd> setAdds;
    private String tempVal;
    // to maintain context
    private XMLSetAdd setAdd;

    public SAXXMLHANDLER() {
        setAdds = new ArrayList<XMLSetAdd>();
    }

    public List<XMLSetAdd> getIds() {
        return setAdds;
    }

    // Event Handlers
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // reset
        tempVal = "";
        if (qName.equals("skus")) {
            setAdd = new XMLSetAdd();
        }
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        tempVal = new String(ch, start, length);
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equals("skus")) {
            setAdds.add(setAdd);
        } else if (qName.equals("id")) {
            setAdd.setId(tempVal);
        }
    }

}
```

my XML SetAdd:

```
public class XMLSetAdd {

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(String Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    private String Id;
}
```

My Async Class:

```
private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<XMLSetAdd>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<XMLSetAdd> news) {

            try 
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < IdsL.size(); i++) 
                {
                    skusList.add(IdsL.get(i).getId());
                    Log.d("XML content",IdsL.get(i).getId());
                }

                skusQuery = new Bundle();
                skusQuery.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skusList);

                GetAllSkusAsync runner = new GetAllSkusAsync();//Some Async to run after
                runner.execute();               
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                Log.d("Error Reading XML: ", ex.toString());
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),"Connection Error!"
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        /*
         * uses HttpURLConnection to make Http request from Android to download
         * the XML file
         */
        private String getXmlFromUrl(String urlString) {
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer("");
            try {
                InputStream stream = null;
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

                HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConnection.connect();

                if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();

                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                    String s = "";
                    while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                        output.append(s);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.d("Error in asyncTask XML: ", ex.toString());
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return output.toString();
        }

        private List<XMLSetAdd> IdsL;

        @Override
        protected List<XMLSetAdd> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            IdsL = null;
            List<XMLSetAdd> myList = null;
            String xml = null;
            for (String url : urls) {
                xml = getXmlFromUrl(url);

                InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
                IdsL = SAXXMLParser.parse(stream);

                myList = SAXXMLParser.parse(stream);
            }
            // stream.close();
            return IdsL;
        }
    }
```

The code which I use to call Async Class:

```
String URL = "http://someaddress/php/sku.xml";
GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
task.execute(new String[] { URL });
```

Now When I run this code and Log the result ,my list returns the last xml child which based on my xml file is "ll" and the rest of xml is not added to the file.

The list should return all of the ids but returns the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you are only adding items to the list when `endElement` is `skus`. You should be adding one element for each id as follows:

```
 public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equals("skus")) {
            // setAdds.add(setAdd); // dont add here..
        } else if (qName.equals("id")) {
            setAdd.setId(tempVal); // if ending with id
            setAdds.add(setAdd); // then add id to the list
        }
 }
```

**Update**

```
 public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // reset
        tempVal = "";
        if (qName.equals("id")) {
            setAdd = new XMLSetAdd(); // new item for each id
        }
 }
```

Comment: Now I get List Array has size of 14 but all elements are ll. which is the last item.

Comment: @user1290467 Oh you have to update the `startElement` method also.. see updated answer

Answer (score 3):

Check following code. Edited SAX XML HANDLER.

```
public class SAXXMLHANDLER extends DefaultHandler {

private List<XMLSetAdd> setAdds;
private String tempVal;
// to maintain context
private XMLSetAdd setAdd;

public SAXXMLHANDLER() {

}

public List<XMLSetAdd> getIds() {
    return setAdds;
}

// Event Handlers
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    // reset
    tempVal = "";
    if (qName.equals("skus")) {
        setAdds = new List<XMLSetAdd>();

    }else if(qName.equals("id")){
         setAdd = new XMLSetAdd();
     }
}

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    tempVal = new String(ch, start, length);
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equals("skus")) {

    } else if (qName.equals("id")) {
        setAdd.setId(tempVal);
        setAdds.add(setAdd);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: in start element when I use setAdds = new List<XMLSetAdd>(); the ide gives me the following error: cannot instantiate type List<SetAdd> but the rest of your code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
   @Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
    curentElement=localName;

    if(qName.equals("skus")){
       setAdd = new XMLSetAdd();
    }
}

 @Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    super.characters(ch, start, length);

    String value = new String(ch, start, length);
    if(curentElement.equals("id")){
        tempVal=value;  
}

   @Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
    curentElement = "";
    if (localName.equals("id")) {
      setAdd.setId(tempVal);
    }else if(localName="skus"){
             setAdds.add(setAdd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

Update your parse

```
public class SAXXMLHANDLER extends DefaultHandler {

    private List<XMLSetAdd> setAdds;
    private String tempVal;
    // to maintain context
    private XMLSetAdd setAdd;

    public SAXXMLHANDLER() {
        setAdds = new ArrayList<XMLSetAdd>();
    }

    public List<XMLSetAdd> getIds() {
        return setAdds;
    }

    // Event Handlers
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // reset
        if (qName.equals("id")) {
            tempVal = "";
            setAdd = new XMLSetAdd();
        }
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        tempVal = new String(ch, start, length);
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equals("id")) {
            setAdd.setId(tempVal);
            setAdds.add(setAdd);
        }
    }
```